# Is there any difference typecasting between (Parent&)child and (Parent)child in c++?

Tags: c++, types, casting

I was just implementing a function and I recognized that there was an error (type error) when a variable was typecasted as `(Parent)child`. But the error fixed when it was typecasted as `(Parent&)child`. Then I checked the type of the variables typecasted and both are same type. Is there a difference or is it probably just because of my code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. `(Parent)child` is most likely object slicing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing. What actually happens in your code one can only say when seeing the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. Casting to an object produces a new prvalue. Casting to a reference produces an lvalue that refers to the base sub object.

P.S. Prefer using C++ style casts (`static_cast`) instead of C-style casts.

Comment: i doubt that this will actually help op, but its an accurate answer to the question they asked ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe that in addition to being an accurate answer to what they asked, this will also help OP to ask the question that they may have been looking for.